# Express.js, get call is returning a 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a GET API call intended to fetch every user in my Logins database. For some reason, I keep on getting 500 calls on it. Here is my code:

```js
const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
});

function fetchUsers(){
    http.get("/getusers").catch(err => {
        console.log("OOF: " + err.message);
    });
}

fetchUsers();
```

This is the routes file:

```js
const users = require("../controller/users.controller.js");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const pathStart = "/api";

// Retrieve all Users
router.get(pathStart + "/getusers", users.findAll);
```

My routes file is being used in my app.js file:

```js
var indexRouter = require('./routes');
var userRouter = require('./routes/users.routes.js');

var app = express();

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);
```

users.controller.js:

```js
// Retrieve all users from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    console.log("extracting users");
    const user = req.query.user;
    var condition = user ? { user: { [Op.like]: `%${user}%` } } : null;

    Users.findAll({ where: condition })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Error occurred when retrieving users"
            })
        });
};
```

This is my output: `OOF: Request failed with status code 500`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of these two lines:

```js
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', userRouter);
```

Basically you will never enter inside `userRouter`, as `indexRouter` catches every request. You need to have something like this below.

In `app.js`:

```js
app.use('/api/', userRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

In `userRouter.js`:

```
const users = require("../controller/users.controller.js");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// const pathStart = "/api"; not needed anymore

// Retrieve all Users
router.get("/getusers", users.findAll);
```

Your fetch logic:

```
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
 }
});

function fetchUsers(){
 http.get("/getusers").catch(err => {
    console.log("OOF: " + err.message);
 });
}

fetchUsers();
```

Comment: I am having the issue where I click on  logout button I get 500 error not sure what is causing it. The google signin part works but when i try to click the logout button in the ejs file i get an error 500